# Som personalizado no Cordova Local Notification

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, plugin, android-assets

Estou tentando personalizar o som para uma notificação usando o **Cordova**. Eu estou usando o plugin [Cordova Local Notification](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/), mas o som não é reproduzido ao exibir a notificação.

Testes realizados:

- Tentei usar o som personalizado no `SDCard`: *funcionou!*
- Tentei usar o som por uma URL: *não funcionou, mas não é o que preciso*
- Tentei usar um som que fica na pasta `www` chamado `beep.mp3`: *não funcionou, e é o que preciso*

> Testes realizados no **Android**, mais preciso que funcione no **iOS** também.

Segue abaixo o código que estou tentando implementar:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
            id: id,
            title: titulo,
            message: msg,
            sound: (config.platform_compilation != 'IOS') ? 'file:///android_assets/www/beep.mp3' : 'www/audio/beep.mp3',
            date: DateOBJ
});
```

A minha verificação do `config.platform_compilation` está correta, o problema é quando tenta reproduzir o som que está em `www`, se coloco esse arquivo no `SDCard` e mudo o caminho na hora da compilação, funciona, porém preciso desse som dentro do *APK/APP* para disponibilizar.

Answer (score 1):

Com a atualização do plugin o som voltou a funcionar, eu só precisei remover ele e colocar novamente.

Segue abaixo um exemplo do uso:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
        id: id,
        title: titulo,
        message: msg,
        sound: (config.platform_compilation != 'IOS') ? 'file:///beep.mp3' : 'www/beep.mp3',
        date: DateOBJ
});
```

> O arquivo encontra-se em /android_asset/www .